# Why is my PHP echo() Command not working as expected?

Tags: php, html

I call a function that I know the sub-string exists, and the echo command will not work the way I want it to.

It always seems to echo the string saying that it does not exist. For this example we can set this as the key.

```
$KEY = "R1*PFD1V1FE1VS1BF1SP1NL2OW1TP1MSD1NR1";

function displayNL( $KEY ) {

    switch ( true ) {
        case ( is_numeric( strpos($KEY, 'NL1') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: May replace with Electric Torch or Lantern    Sidelights: May replace with Electric Torch or Lantern  Sternlight: May replace with Electric Torch or Lantern  Other Lights: -   Dayshapes: - ";
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL2') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: May replace with Electric Torch or Lantern    Sidelights: May replace with Electric Torch or Lantern   Sternlight: May replace with Electric Torch or Lantern Other Lights: All Around Red over All Around Green on Masthead (OPTIONAL)   Dayshapes: -" ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL3') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: May replace with Electric Torch or Lantern    Sidelights: May replace with Electric Torch or Lantern  Sternlight: May replace with Electric Torch or Lantern  Other Lights: All Around Red over All Around Green on Masthead (OPTIONAL)   Dayshapes: When under power and in International Waters, Cone with Apex Down" ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL4') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: May replace with All Around White Light   Sidelights: May forego if impracticle to mount  Sternlight: May replace with Other Lights: All Around White Light - Dayshapes: - " ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL5') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: May replace with All Around White Light   Sidelights: May have Sidelights Combined in Single Lantern on Centerline    Sternlight: May replace with Other Lights: All Around White Light   -   Dayshapes: - " ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL6') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: Masthead Light Not Required   Sidelights: May have Single Lantern with Sidelights and Sternlights on Mast Sternlight: May have Single Lantern with Sidelights and Sternlights on Mast Other Lights: All Around Red over All Around Green on Masthead (OPTIONAL)   Dayshapes: - " ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL7') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: Masthead Light Not Required   Sidelights: May have Single Lantern with Sidelights and Sternlights on Mast Sternlight: May have Single Lantern with Sidelights and Sternlights on Mast Other Lights: All Around Red over All Around Green on Masthead (OPTIONAL)   Dayshapes: When under power and in International Waters, Cone with Apex Down " ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL8') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: Required  Sidelights: May have Sidelights Combined in Single Lantern on Centerline    Sternlight: Required    Other Lights: - Dayshapes: - " ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL9') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: Required  Sidelights: Required    Sternlight: Required    Other Lights: - Dayshapes: - " ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL1*0') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: Required  Sidelights: Required    Sternlight: Required    Other Lights: All Around Red over All Around Green on Masthead  Dayshapes: - " ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL1*1') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: Required  Sidelights: Required    Sternlight: Required    Other Lights: All Around Red over All Around Green on Masthead  Dayshapes: When under power, Cone with Apex Down " ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL1*2') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: Required, 2   Sidelights: Required    Sternlight: Required    Other Lights: - Dayshapes: - " ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL1*3') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: Required, 2   Sidelights: Required    Sternlight: Required    Other Lights: All Around Red over All Around Green on Masthead  Dayshapes: - " ;
            break;
        case ( is_numeric ( strpos($KEY, 'NL1*4') ) ) :
            echo "Masthead Light: Required, 2   Sidelights: Required    Sternlight: Required    Other Lights: All Around Red over All Around Green on Masthead  Dayshapes: When under power, Cone with Apex Down " ;
            break;
        default:
            echo "Make sure you selected somthing OR This Combination Does Not Exists ";

    }
}


displayNL( $KEY ) ;
```

Comment: Your code is abusing the switch for something that would be far better served by an array or a set of ifs. Also NL1*0 will never happen since it will be caught by just NL1

Comment: What does your `strpos($KEY, 'NL2')` returns?

Comment: I will check real quick

Comment: This is weird code. Regardless the `switch` usage, the `strpos` checking is wrong since you need to check it against in `!==FALSE` rather some number.

Comment: It isnt returning anything. It just is blank

Comment: @JRizzly so this is why it's never found. @vlzvl `strpos` returns position numbers, so it's possible to check if it's number!

Comment: @Justinas, it also returns `FALSE` which results to `0` but it's a number..

Comment: Yes, so if it is a number or found in that case it should echo the statement. Right?

Comment: @JRizzly Your code runs perfectly for me, displaying the NL2 switch case. Is this your **exact and current** code and is error reporting activated ?

Comment: No, I shortened it to make it easier as this is the problem. Shall  I put the whole thing here?

Comment: Your strpos is returning false. That is why `strpos($KEY, 'NL2')` returns blank. And 'false' !== 0, so it is not numeric, it is boolean

Comment: @JRizzly Since the shortened version works and the whole thing doesn't, yes, you have to give us the whole code (or at least a bigger part)

Comment: What is weird is I have like 9 other functions all like this in the same file, and somehow this one doesnt work like this. I did find that changing the case statement to strpos($KEY, 'NL2') !=== true works! yay, I dont know why.

Comment: Why not something like preg_match("/NL\d{1}\*\d{1}|NL\d{1}/", $KEY, $output_array);

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...I think the bug is in something else. If it does not return anything, try to debug the code with a die('break'); before this code block. This is the simplest debug method you can use to identify the bug.

If the die doesn't work, there is an error above the code block.